# Change values to indices in a `Conkin.Traversable` without `unsafeCoerce`

Tags: haskell, traversal, existential-type, data-kinds

Using the `conkin` package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conkin

I want to be able to take any `Conkin.Traversable` and dump it out to a `Tuple` leaving behind *indices* into that `Tuple` so that I can reconstruct it.

I'm using a few language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators             #-}
```

Module declaration

```
module TupleDump where
```

Imports

```
import           Control.Monad.State  (State, runState)
import qualified Control.Monad.State  as State
import           Data.Functor.Compose (getCompose)
import           Data.Functor.Const   (Const (Const), getConst)
import           Conkin               (Dispose (..), Flip (..), Tuple (..))
import qualified Conkin
```

I want to not have to use an unsafeCoerce, but can't see a way around it:

```
import           Unsafe.Coerce        (unsafeCoerce)
```

Let's define an `Index` as:

```
data Index (xs :: [k]) (x :: k) where
  IZ :: Index (x ': xs) x
  IS :: Index xs i -> Index (x ': xs) i
```

We can use an index to extract an item from a `Tuple`:

```
(!) :: Tuple xs a -> Index xs x -> a x
(!) (Cons x _) IZ      = x
(!) (Cons _ xs) (IS i) = xs ! i
```

We should be able to take anything which is an instance of `Conkin.Traversable` and *dump* it to a `Tuple` leaving behind an Index in place of each element. Then from the structure of indices and the tuple we can reconstruct the original Traversable structure:

```
data TupleDump t a = forall xs. TupleDump (t (Index xs)) (Tuple xs a)

toTupleDump :: forall (t :: (k -> *) -> *) (a :: k -> *). Conkin.Traversable t
  => t a -> TupleDump t a
fromTupleDump :: Conkin.Functor t => TupleDump t a -> t a
```

The reconstruction part is easy:

```
fromTupleDump (TupleDump inds vals) = Conkin.fmap (vals !) inds
```

This question is specifically how to implement `toTupleDump`. Below is my best attempt so far:

---

It involves a lot of helper functions and an `unsafeCoerce`

Existentially quantified functors:

```
data Some (a :: k -> *) = forall (x :: k). Some (a x)
```

Given an `Int`, construct some `Index`:

```
mkIndex :: Tuple xs a -> Int -> Some (Index xs)
mkIndex Nil _ = error "Index out of bounds"
mkIndex _ n | n < 0 = error "Index out of bounds"
mkIndex (Cons _ _) 0 = Some IZ
mkIndex (Cons _ xs) n = case mkIndex xs (n - 1) of Some i -> Some $ IS i
```

Given a list of existentially quantified functors, group them into a (flipped) `Tuple`:

```
fromList :: [Some a] -> Some (Flip Tuple a)
fromList [] = Some $ Flip Nil
fromList (Some x : xs) = case fromList xs of
  Some (Flip t) -> Some (Flip (Cons x t))
```

Traversal inside a `Prelude.Applicative` (rather than a `Conkin.Applicative`)

```
traverseInPrelude :: (Prelude.Applicative f, Conkin.Traversable t)
  => (forall x. a x -> f (b x)) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverseInPrelude fn t =
  Conkin.fmap (unComposeConst . getFlip) . getCompose <$>
    getDispose (Conkin.traverse (Dispose . fmap ComposeConst . fn) t)

newtype ComposeConst a b c = ComposeConst {unComposeConst :: a b}
```

And now we can define `toTupleDump`:

```
toTupleDump t =
```

We'll track the index as just an `Int` at first and dump our elements to a normal list.
Since we're building the list with `(:)`, it's going to be backwards.

```
  let
    nextItem :: forall (x :: k). a x -> State (Int, [Some a]) (Const Int x)
    nextItem x = do
      (i, xs') <- State.get
      State.put (i + 1, Some x : xs')
      return $ Const i
    (res, (_, xs)) = runState (traverseInPrelude nextItem t) (0, [])
  in
```

Now we reverse the list and convert it to a `Tuple`:

```
  case fromList (reverse xs) of
    Some (Flip (tup :: Tuple xs a)) ->
```

And we need to `fmap` over the `res` structure changing all the `Int`s into `Index`es

```
      let
        indexedRes = Conkin.fmap (coerceIndex . mkIndex tup . getConst) res
```

Here's that `unsafeCoerce`. Since this approach involves two passes over the structure, we have to let the typechecker know that on the second pass, the type parameter is the same as it was on the first pass.

```
        coerceIndex :: forall x. Some (Index xs) -> Index xs x
        coerceIndex (Some i) = unsafeCoerce i
      in
      TupleDump indexedRes tup
```

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using type-level `Nat`s in your code? I don't understand if e.g. `nextItem` is solely dependent on some runtime values.

Comment: Where might type-level `Nat`s be useful?

Comment: In being able to define indexes at the type level so you wouldn't have to coerce them, since a type-level index would always yield the same type on the `Foldable` - though that might require a type-level notion of the length of the `Foldable` to implement the traversal and construction of `res`. This is more speculation than a concrete design.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's not enough for me to grasp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I conjecture that it is not possible to implement `toTupleDump` without `unsafeCoerce`.

The problem can be reduced to computing `fillWithIndexes`

```
data SomeIndex t = forall xs. SomeIndex (t (Index xs))

fillWithIndexes :: forall (t :: (k -> *) -> *) (a :: k -> *). Conkin.Traversable t
  => t a -> SomeIndex t
```

where `xs` is the list of types collected in the traversal of the value of type `t a`. However, the type system can't guarantee that traversals over the result `t (Index xs)` produce the same list of types `xs`.

If the `Traversable` instance of `t` does not respect the `Traversable` laws, it is possible to concoct an implementation which actually changes the types.

```
data T a = TBool (a Bool) | TChar (a Char)
instance Conkin.Functor T where
  fmap f (TBool a) = TBool (f a)
  fmap f (TChar a) = TChar (f a)

instance Conkin.Foldable T where
  foldr f z (TBool a) = f a z
  foldr f z (TChar a) = f a z

instance Conkin.Traversable T where
  traverse f (TBool a) = Conkin.pure (Compose (TChar undefined))
  traverse f (TChar a) = Conkin.pure (Compose (TBool undefined))
```

Can't we rule this case out by assuming the `Traversable` laws hold? Yes, we can rule it out, but the typechecker can't, which means that we must use `unsafeCoerce`.